# Servlet chaining with “jquery-1.8.2.min.js” and “jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js” does not work?

Tags: jquery, servlets, jquery-mobile

I have written code in which a request to ServletA will call ServletB which in turn redirect the user to an external page (i.e. PayPal page).

The code works fine and redirects to the correct page until included the jquery and jquery.mobile to the initial jsp page.

```
<html> 
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/myApp/ServletA">Call to ServletA</a>
</body>
</html>
```

On debugging I know that I reach ServletB but for some reason I do not get redirected to the external link. The page only hangs with ‘**Error loading page**’ briefly appearing.

Comment: Can the servlet be requested via Ajax? Because unless you are setting data-ajax="false" on the link, JQM will request the page via AJAX, grab what's inside your servlet `div data-role="page`, discard the rest and transition to the new page.

Comment: @Gajotres no, the jsp isn't XHTML; but it is well formatted. Would making it XHTML make a difference?

Comment: No, I had a case with JSF and XHTML where <!DOCTYPE html> was causing a problem with rel="external"

Comment: @frequent I think that is totally correct; looking the http headers. I've now added `data-ajax="false"` to the link and it worked. Thank you both.

Comment: @Ithar: please check my answer below, so the next person looking for the same question on Stack Overflow has the answer right away. Thanks!

Comment: @Gajotres: JSF uses XHTML as XML based template to generate HTML (so the client ultimately retrieves just HTML). The problem is not caused by XHTML itself. This is utter nonsense.

Comment: @BalusC: Chrome browser has a known error when XHTML files are used with jQuery Mobile. For some reason it wraps everything with DIV block and that is causing jQM pages to brake. It can only be solved when <!DOCTYPE html> is removed.

Comment: @Gajotres: it's likely just delivered with the wrong content type which is sniffed based on URL extension. Use `<f:view contentType>` to force your own, or remap it on `*.html`. You can just keep using XHTML to generate HTML. XHTML doesn't run in client, but in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JQM will request all pages via AJAX. When doing so, JQM is loading the page and grabs what is inside the first `<div:jqmData(role="page"></div>`.

If the servlet page is not a JQM page, the link will not work.

So in order to load a 3rd party provider or servlet page, you need to tell JQM to not use AJAX on the link by specifying `data-ajax="false"`, which will override JQM and do a regular page load.

This will leave your application, which you should be aware of when doing so.

Comment: Would vote up but don't have enough reputation; this solved my problem.